# Rails 3 - how to solve different count of parameters in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, url-routing

I am thinking about question in routing... I have for example following in URL:

> example.com/john

and for this URL I did this in routes

> match "*a" => "people#person"

and in controller
  def profile
    #I have "john" in params[:a] variable 
    ...
  end

And know I am thinking, how to do following URL

> example.com/john/something

How I should edit my routes and my controller for this shape of URL. I am newbie in Rails, and a bit confused yet in routing...

Thank you

Comment: `something` is the another parameter in URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
match ":a(/:b)" => "people#person"

# controller
def person
  a = params[:a]
  b = params[:b]
end
```

Comment: thank you, I will try it... and exist any more elegant/cleaner way to do? In this case, I have to do conditions in my `person` controller